# 400 amp meter base to dual disconnects to dual 200 amp panels. What wire?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

AHJ: WA State L&I. POCO: Mason County PUD #1

I'm feeding two 200 Amp panels from a 400 Amp (320 class) meter base. I've seen the Siemens combo, but our POCO requirements mean it can't be used. They are saying to use an Eaton 324N for the meter base. Left and right of the meter base, I'll have Q2200MRBE 200 amp disconnects (to keep NEC 2020 happy). On the other side of the wall from each disconnect (inside the garage), there will be a 200 amp panel (HOM3060M200PCVP). I know these could be main lugs and not have a breaker, but it's cheaper to buy main breaker panels.

Given how narrow the disconnect box is (7.56 in), I want to use CU, not AL, because I'm concerned otherwise about bend radius. The wires from the panel to the disconnects will enter at the bottom of the side, then need to feed up to the top and bend over, down to the 200 amp breaker.

I *think* I should run three wires of 2/0 CU from the panel to each 200 amp disconnect. Does that sound right? I'm thinking THHN-2. Three similar wires would then feed down from the breaker, through the wall to the 200 amp panel in the garage. Or can the neutral wire be a smaller gauge?

And then, a ground wire (#6 Bare CU? #4?) will go to each disconnect, and then a ground wire (same gauge) will go from each disconnect to the panel on the other side of the wall, in the garage.

All distances should be short. I think I need a 6" nipple between the panel and each disconnect, and then a tight nipple through the wall from each disconnect to its panel. So, relative cost of CU vs AL shouldn't be a big issue. I'm going to use 2" dia nipples so fill/pull isn't an issue.

Comment: On what basis do you get to use 2/0 (https://www.cerrowire.com/products/resources/tables-calculators/ampacity-charts/ says 175A) instead of 3/0?

Comment: I don't know. That's why I'm asking. All other answers on this site cover AL. I couldn't find one for CU. You chose the value for 75 degrees, not the value for 90 degrees, which would be 195. When would one apply over the other? In various answers, I've seen mention that you can cover 85% not the full 100% - not sure if that's correct and when it might apply. Anyway, it's *because* of all these various things mentioned in various answers that I didn't know the right answer, so I was asking.

Comment: Copper is smaller, which is an advantage. It is more expensive, which is a disadvantage. But for a few feet, cost is usually a non-issue. As far as 75 vs. 90, for *most* things 75 is the number to use. You can only use 90 if all the various components being connected are rated for 90, which is usually not the case. 90 does come into play on issues of multiple circuits in one conduit, but that doesn't apply here. The 85% thing is actually 83% and it applies to an entire utility service - e.g., if you have 200A service and run off the lugs from the main panel to a 200A rated subpanel then

Comment: can continue the 83% number - i.e., you never have to use larger wires than the main feed. But in your case it is 400A -> 200A x 2, so each 200A has to use 100% rating, not 83%.

Comment: Thanks. I found the refs in NEC. Ugh. But I understand. So, sounds like 3/0 CU. Does that go for the neutral wire too? And what size ground? Based on 250.28(D)(2) and Table 250.102(C)(1), for 2./0 or 3/0 CU, I need #4 CU. I know if I had 1 enclosure, I'd feed that bare CU from one ground rod to the next to the service disconnect enclosure. With two, must I have two separate wires, one per box, or can I feed one wire (no splices) from one ground rod to the next to the lug on the 1st service disconnect, through the conduit connecting the meter base and then the 2nd disconnect box?

Comment: Pretty sure you can't downsize the neutral. As far as ground, 4 AWG. Ground rods/wire to the two disconnects (same wire to both). Then a separate 4 AWG wire from each disconnect to its subpanel. Bond neutral to ground in each disconnect. Do not bond neutral to ground (and keep ground wires off the neutral bar) in the 200A subpanels. Some disconnects can be "pure disconnect" but these are clearly designed (read the manual) to have ground.