# What conduits/nipples/bushings do I need to connect a 400a meter base to dual disconnects to dual 200a panels?

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

Lots of info on configuration can be found here: [400 amp meter base to dual disconnects to dual 200 amp panels. What wire?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/287375/400-amp-meter-base-to-dual-disconnects-to-dual-200-amp-panels-what-wire)

There's a 3" conduit feeding underground service to the Meter base. It's PVC. I'm assuming the bushing there should also be plastic.

Between the meter base and the two outside disconnects, I need about a 2" dia x 6" nipple. Is there any requirement about whether this is metal or PVC? Any requirements about metal or PVC for the bushings on either end? Any requirements if the bushings on either end must be tied to ground if metal?

Between the outside disconnects and the inside panels (right on the other side of the wall), I'll have a very short 2" dia nipple. Same questions about metal vs PVC for this nipple and its bushings.

Answer (score 1):

### I'd use PVC here, provided the utility is OK with it of course

I personally would use 2" PVC for these nipples; this removes the need to bond the nipple at each end, and also removes a "sneak path" for neutral current from the picture, as such a path can violate NEC 250.6.  Do double check with your utility, though -- I have seen a few odd utility specifications that require RMC between the meter and an adjacent main disconnect for some odd reason.

Comment: Thanks. I'll check with them. You talked about meter base to disconnect. Same for disconnect to panel?

Comment: @TomGetzinger -- disco to panel you have more flexibility on -- it really depends on whether you want your emergency disconnect to be the service disconnecting means or a non-service emergency disconnect

Comment: The boxes we're looking at state they are service rated. I've seen others that state they are not. So,, I think that means we have the option. Looking at 200 amp breaker panels vs main lug panels, you can get the former for ~$200 and the latter for ~$130. So, if it isn't too late to change, I'm thinking of skipping main breakers in the panels and the disconnect to be the 200 amp breakers.

Comment: @TomGetzinger -- yeah, getting a main lug SqD panel also means you get a ground bar included in the package :) which helps in your situation